# Mongoose/Mongodb update element from inner array and return the updated element

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update an element inside an array placed in a mongodb document. Usually, after an update action, I am getting the whole document, but I would like the newly updated element to be returned:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6471fe4a0045e48a0c6193ba"),
  gateways: [
    {
      _id: '5231db1f-b79a-4dc3-a387-6f08ad7b6857',
      name: 'Babylon Dev',
      right: 'owner'
    }
  ],
  __v: 0,
  notifications: [
    {
      type: 'confirm',
      title: 'Gateway whitelist request!',
      description: '6471fe4a0045e48a0c6193ba wants to share data from gateway 5231db1f-b79a-4dc3-a387-6f08ad7b6857 with you.',
      actions: [Array],
      from: '6471fe4a0045e48a0c6193ba',
      subject: '5231db1f-b79a-4dc3-a387-6f08ad7b6857',
      status: 'unread',
      _id: new ObjectId("64b6791adbf7bb6eaa528cf2")
    },
    {
          type: 'confirm',
          title: 'Gateway whitelist request!',
          description: '6471fe4a0045e48a0c6193ba wants to share data from gateway 5231db1f-b79a-4dc3-a387-6f08ad7b6857 with you.',
          actions: [Array],
          from: '6471fe4a0045e48a0c6193ba',
          subject: '5231db1f-b79a-4dc3-a387-6f08ad7b6857',
          status: 'unread',
          _id: new ObjectId("64b6791adbf7bb6eaa528cf5")
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to update the notification `status` property from `unread` to `read` or `confirmed` and to return the updated notification. Is there a clean way to do this in a single query? The query whould update based on the `_id` of the document and the `_id` of the notification.
The user schema:

```
@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop( { type: [ GatewaySchema ], default: [] } )
  @IsArray( { each: true } )
  @Type( () => Gateway )
  @Expose()
  gateways?: Array<Gateway>;

  @Prop( { type: [ NotificationSchema ], default: [] } )
  @IsArray( { each: true } )
  @Type( () => Notification )
  @Expose()
  notifications?: Array<Notification>;
}
```

The notification schema:

```
@Schema()
export class Notification {

  @IsMongoId()
  @Expose()
  @Prop( { type: Types.ObjectId } )
  _id: Types.ObjectId;

  @IsString()
  @Expose()
  @Prop( { type: String, enum: NotificationLevels, default: NotificationLevels.info } )
  type?: NotificationLevels;

  @IsString()
  @Expose()
  @Prop( { type: String, required: true } )
  title: string;

  @IsString()
  @Expose()
  @Prop( { type: String, required: true } )
  description: string;

  @IsString()
  @Expose()
  @Prop( { type: Array, enum: NotificationAction, default: [ NotificationAction.mark ], required: false } )
  actions?: Array<NotificationAction>;

  @IsMongoId()
  @Prop( { type: Types.ObjectId, required: true } )
  for: Types.ObjectId;;

  @IsMongoId()
  @Prop( { type: Types.ObjectId, required: true } )
  from: Types.ObjectId;

  @IsUUID()
  @Prop( { type: String, required: true } )
  subject: string;

  @IsString()
  @Expose()
  @Prop( { type: String, enum: NotificationStatus, default: NotificationStatus.unread } )
  status: NotificationStatus;
}
```

Progress:

In order to update the notification I am using this method:

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate( { _id: userId, 'notifications._id': notificationId }, { $set: { 'notifications.$.status': 'confirmed' } }, { arrayFilters: [ { _id: notificationId } ], projection: { 'notifications.$': 1 }, new: true } );
```

This is good, but I would like the returned object to be the notification that was just updated. Kind of like an aggregate query. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to update the `status` field to different values or the same value for each notification?

Comment: The status value.

Comment: Can you add the model code and the update action you mention?

Comment: @SuleymanSah , what do you mean by that? I am asking how could I make the update based on the document objectid and the notification objectid. I don't understand what model/update action you want me to add in the question.

Comment: Don't you use mongoose? If you don't use mongoose, remove the mongoose tag from the question

Comment: I am using mongoose. You want the model of the document? The Schema? Help me here a little. I don't understand what is not clear from the question.

Comment: Yes schema code, and the update code.

Comment: I've added the schema. The update code I don't have since that is what I am asking for.

I am trying somethiong like this: `findByIdAndUpdate( userId, { $set: { notifications: { status: 'confirmed' } } }, { arrayFilters: [ { _id: notificationId } ] } );`

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this. You can pass the field names that you are updating to the projection option in the find one and update method.

For example:

```
    [
        { _id: 1, name: 'Ryan', gender: 'M' },
        { _id: 2, name: 'Joanna', gender: 'F'
    ]

db.students.findOneAndUpdate({_id:1},{gender:'F'},{projection:{gender:1}});
```

Maybe this will help you get the desired output.

Comment: It's quite different in my case since I am trying to update something inside an array. Updating a property like name or gender is simple in the case you described, but my conditions are more specific:

1, Update an element inside notification array based on the `_id` of the document and the `_id` of the notification

2. Return the updated notification as the result of the query, not the whole document.